# Laravel - View [layouts.backend] not found

Tags: php, laravel, themes

I am following a tutorial for creating a CMS in Laravel, but have been stuck on the part that deals with creating themes: It shows an error saying the file can't be found.

The tutorial was in Laravel 5, but I am using Laravel 5.4.

```
namespace App\View;

    use Illuminate\View\FileViewFinder;

    class ThemeViewFinder extends FileViewFinder
    {
        protected $activeTheme;

        protected $basePath;

        public function setBasePath($path)
        {
            $this->basePath = $path;
        }

        public function setActiveTheme($theme)
        {
            $this->activeTheme = $theme;

            array_unshift($this->paths, $this->basePath.'/'.$theme.'/views');

        }


    }


 $this->app->singleton('theme.finder',function($app){
           $finder=new ThemeViewFinder($app['files'],$app['config']['view.paths']);

           $config=$app['config']['cms.theme'];

            $original_finder = $this->app['view']->getFinder();


           $finder->setBasePath($app['path.base'].'/'.$config['folder']);
           $finder->setActiveTheme($config['active']);

           return $finder;
        });
```

Below is the error message:

[image]

Comment: Did you create the `layouts.backend` file and place it in your `views` folder?

Comment: More specifically, is there a `resources/views/layouts/backend.php` or `resources/views/layouts/backend.blade.php` file in your project?

Comment: no the layout is in another folder which i get from a config file here is what the config file contains `return [
    'theme'=>[
        'folder'=>'themes',
        'active'=>'default'
    ]
];`

Comment: To help you debug, add a `getBasePath` method to the `ThemeViewFinder` and where you consume it check the base path, also check what `$this->paths` contains. I presume the following exists: `C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsites\myblog\themes\default\views\layouts\backend.blade.php`